# BZflag won't open on extended monitor

Tags: kubuntu, external-monitor

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) on a ASUS laptop with a second monitor plugged into the HDMI port.  BZFlag will open and run on the laptop screen but I cannot get it to run on the extended monitor.  I've made the extended monitor the primary monitor but BZflag opens on the extended monitor but the game runs on the laptop monitor.  How can I run the game on the extended monitor?  I've opened window rules in system settings and below is what appears.  What do I do to move the BZflag window?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the entry in the task bar and select *More Actions* then *Special Application Settings* to create a window rule. In the *Size & Position* tab check *Screen* and *Force* to the screen you want.

Comment: If I click on the entry in the task bar the only option is to unpin or task manager settings.  There is no option for More Actions.

Comment: The question is labeled as Kubuntu which has these options as part of the Plasma desktop. You can also access the same dialog by using the Window Rules tool.

Comment: I am running Kubuntu and I do have Window Rules under System Settings but have no clue what the dialogs mean or how to change the BZflag window.  Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: when I open BZflag, the cursur does not let me escape the game to select Screen and Force to screen.

Comment: Can you run the game in windowed mode or alt tab?

Comment: The game as installed, runs only in fullscreen mode.  Alt Tab has no effect.